# Pd4ml not supporting Thai language and also some south Indian languages

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pd4ml

I give 
ನೀವು ಹೇಗಿದ್ದೀರಿ == kannada language which is Tunga font

and telugu, tamil and thai language and along with hebrew sometimes.

it gives output with special characters.

for example :: for kannada "ನೀವು ಹೇಗಿದ್ದೀರಿ"
it generates, "à²¨à²¿à³•à²µà³• à²¹à³†à³•à²—à²¿à²¦à³•à²¦à²¿à³•à²°à²¿"
I have used,

my code includes

"pd4ml.useTTF(fontMappingFile, true);"

fontMappingFile is path to the fontmapping.properties which contains all these fonts and also in system, all fonts are present.

fontmapping.properties is file genrated following link
http://pd4ml.com/cookbook/pd4ml_pdf_true_type_fonts.htm

on debug
pd4ml.enableDebugInfo()
i get in console similar to as in link but the solution from pd4ml dint work.
http://pd4ml.com/support/html-pdf-faq-f1/pd4ml-pro-version-ttf-issue-t967.html
I am doing in java.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: added the changes, due to my company policy i am not able to post the code snippet, please tell me how can i brief my problem alternatively.                   Thank you.

Comment: Well it makes it very hard to help you if we can't reproduce the problem. This doesn't need to be your *real* code - just a short but complete example demonstrating the same problem. For example, it should use hard-coded text rather than any business data.

Comment: File tempFile = File.createTempFile( "pd4ml", ".pdf" );
java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream( tempFile );

PD4ML pd4ml = new PD4ML();
pd4ml.setHtmlWidth( 800 );
pd4ml.useTTF( "/convertpdf/fonts", true );
pd4ml.render( "xyz");

Comment: http://pd4ml.com/support/html-css-to-pdf-rendering-issues-f3/i-cannot-parse-thai-font-with-taglib-t994.html                                                                      please check if this is helpful

Comment: Please put your code in the question, not in comments - and make it a short but complete progrma, not just a snippet.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your help.

Comment: I figured out the solution, creating fontmapping.properties file to configure in my application and upgrading pd4ml version